# How do I create a combined colour plot with legend overlaying two marks in Spatstat?

Tags: r, legend, spatstat

I wanted to create a combined colour plot of two marks in Spatstat with a legend to show the species as well as the diameters of multiple species in one point process pattern.

I started with this plot:

```
    set.seed(42)
    species  <- LETTERS[1:16]
    diameter <- sample(15:50,16,TRUE)
    x        <- sample(2:18,16,TRUE)
    y        <- sample(2:18,16,TRUE)
    library(spatstat)
    Dat <- data.frame(x,y,species,diameter)
    X   <- as.ppp(Dat,W=square(20))
    marks(X)$species <- factor(marks(X)$species)
    ccc <- (1:16)[as.numeric(factor(marks(X)$species))]
    # Here ccc will just be 1:16 since there are the same number
    # of species as points, but in general ccc will be a vector of
    # length = npoints(X), with entries determined by the species
    # associated with the given point.
    newPal  <- vector("list",4)
    newPal[[1]] <- colorRampPalette(c("green","red"))(10)
    newPal[[2]] <- heat.colors(16)
    newPal[[3]] <- topo.colors(16)

newPal[[4]] <- terrain.colors(16)
for(k in 1:4) {
    palette(newPal[[k]])
    plot(X,which.marks="diameter",maxsize=1,main="")
    plot(X,which.marks="diameter",maxsize=1,bg=ccc,add=TRUE)
    if(k < 4) readline("Go? ")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need any planar point pattern file "X" (.ppp) with "dbh" (diameter at breast height) as a numeric variable and "species" (as a factor numerically coded (but still categorical variable)) as marks.

Thanks to Rolf Turner for this:

```
dbhAndSpecies <- function(X,palfn=c("hcl","heat","terrain","topo","cm","rainbow"),
                          palnm="Spectral",...) {
library(spatstat)
if(!(all(c("species","dbh") %in% names(marks(X))))) {
    whinge <- paste0("The marks of \"X\" must be a data frame",
                     " having columns \"species\" and \"dbh\".\n")
    stop(whinge)
}

X  <- shift(X,origin="bottomleft")
xr <- Window(X)$xrange
yr <- Window(X)$yrange
X  <- affine(X,mat=diag(c(5/xr[2],10/yr[2])))

lbls <- c("Ash","Beech","Lime","FieldMaple","Oak","WychElm",
          "Alder","An","Birch","Sallow","CrabApple","Blackthorn",
          "Hawthorn","Larch","WildService","Whitebeam","Holly","Privet",
          "Yew","Rose","Dogwood","GuelderRose","Hazel","Spindle")
lbls <- substr(lbls,1,5)
ok   <- (1:24) %in% marks(X)$species
marks(X)$species <- factor(marks(X)$species,levels=(1:24)[ok],labels=lbls[ok])
nspec <- length(levels(marks(X)$species))
palfn <- match.arg(palfn)
if(palfn=="hcl") {
    pal <- hcl.colors(n=nspec,palette=palnm)
} else {
    if(palfn != "rainbow") palfn <- paste0(palfn,".colors")
    palfn <- get(palfn)
    pal <- palfn(n=nspec)
}
kul <- (1:nspec)[as.numeric(factor(marks(X)$species))]
oldPal <- palette(pal)
on.exit(palette(oldPal))
OP <- par(xpd=NA)
on.exit(par(OP),add=TRUE)
plot(X,which.marks="dbh",maxsize=1,...)
plot(X,which.marks="dbh",maxsize=1,bg=kul,add=TRUE)
leg <- levels(marks(X)$species)
legend("right",pch=20,col=1:nspec,legend=leg,inset=-0.02,title="Species")
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this will not work in future versions of `spatstat`. It exploits a bug in the `spatstat` code which will be closed soon. You'll need to use base graphics to make this plot soon.